# Adding an HUD spinner to a label as a subview

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a label `textLabel` that I want to display a spinner over.

I have the Xamarin component `BTProgressHUD` and use the following code to display a spinner across the whole view:

```
BTProgressHUD.Show();
```

However, I want to display a spinner ONLY in my `textLabel` and not the whole view.

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with this component. You should use your own `UIActivityIndicatorView` instead, it is quite easy.

For example:

```
var spinner = new UIActivityIndicatorView(UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray) {
    Center = new CGPoint(textLabel.Frame.Right - 32, textLabel.Center.Y)
};
View.AddSubview(spinner);
spinner.StartAnimating();
```

Comment: If I had a label, could I just add a UIActivityIndicatorView with the AddSubview method?

Comment: Yes, that is possible as well.

Comment: If I want to not center the spinner and have it on the right side of my label, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: I have updated the code to accommodate this. You have to play a bit with the 32, though.